# Is there a way to know what proportion of code is covered by test with CXX test?

Tags: c++, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna, cxxtest

I am using CXX test to do unit testing in my program. I would like to know if there is a way to know what percentage of the program is covered by tests or have any other metric to see how well the program is covered by tests.

I am programming in C++ using Eclipse Luna under Ubuntu 14.04.

Thank you

Comment: I'm using gcov/lcov, to do so.

Comment: that's a good alternative. It seems very nice, I might talk about it to my team and we'll probably switch having a metric is impossible in CXX  test.
Thx a lot ! :)

Comment: gcov, is independent of the testing framework that's actually used. You don't have to switch to a different one.